# How to send different components and then check their type?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jcombobox, jcomponent

So I have a `JComboBox` and `JTextField` in view. I want to send them to model so I tried:

```
functionName(component);
```

And then in model:

```
functionName(JComponent component) { 
    switch(component.type){
      case JComboBox:
         System.out.println("true");
         break;
      case JTextField:
          System.out.println("false");
          break;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried .class instead of .type? Also please outline what your particular issue is

Comment: Sorry, I have a problem I dont know what to use instead of JComponent because it does not work

Comment: The issue appears to be that you are comparing using a .type parameter instead of a .class comparison - try the following. switch(component.getClass()) { case JComboBox.class: break;} etc.

Comment: Having to check the type of the source component seems not just bug prone, but also an XY problem. See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: Why do you want to do that? A model represents your data, why do want it to care about components of the gui layer?